# MacBook Pro internet recovery not reinstalling Mac OS X

Tags: mac, internet-recovery

I've got a MacBook Pro 13" from 2012 which I recently swapped the hard drive to an SSD, as the hard drive was dying. When I start up internet recovery to reinstall Mac OS X Lion, everything seems fine until I hit "Install", when the Mac freaks out and says there are -2.1 billion hours remaining on the install. I've tried to use a seperate installer app downloaded to a USB and run through the terminal, but that says it cannot find the components on the internet needed to reinstall macOS. Do you know what's happening?

Comment: What OS are you trying to install on it?

Comment: Why did you choose to install Lion instead of Catalina? In other words, why did you choose the OS X that came with Mac over choosing the latest macOS available for your Mac?

Comment: Internet Recovery will only let me install Lion, if anyone knows how to install another macOS that'd be helpful

Comment: What was the latest version of OS X/macOS that was ever installed on your Mac? Should I assume this is Lion?

Comment: Yes, it was Lion

Comment: What is a "separate installer app"? Where did you download this from? I know Apple provides a `.dmg` file which can be downloaded to your Mac. A USB bootable flash drive Lion installer can be made from this `.dmg` download. This installer should not require components on the internet to install Lion. This seems to differ from what you did. Can you explain further what steps you used? You are asking *"Do you know what's happening?"*, but I do not know enough about what you did to be able to answer your question.

Comment: Maxwell: Did you find a solution to your problem?